Eigenvalue of square of a matrix
If I am given a vector $w$, and a matrix $A$ such that
$A^2w = 0$
and I know that $A$ is not nilpotent, is it correct to say that
$Aw = 0$?
Edit:
Originally I had thought the above statement to be true. My argument is the following:
Assume to the contrary that $Aw \neq 0$. Since we can construct a linearly independent basis from the eigenvectors of $A$, we can expand the result of $Aw$ in terms of its eigenvectors ${v_i}$,
$Aw = \sum_i c_iv_i$
for some constants $c_i$. Further multiplying the result by $A$ gives,
$\sum_i \lambda_ic_iv_i = 0$
But since the set of eigenvectors $\{v_i\}$ is linearly independent, the only possible solution is if $\{v_i\}=0$.Then by contradiction, the statement is proved.
The answers below have given valid counterexamples so I am wrong. However, I am unable to see where my argument goes wrong.

What have you tried?

What does the question have to do with eigenvalues, if $w$ is a general vector?

Take $A$ as a block matrix by a nonzero matrix $B$ with $B^2=0$ and a row and column $(0,0,\ldots ,1)$ added. This gives a counterexample.

Being the zero matrix and mapping one particular vector to zero are very different things for a matrix. You can exploit that fact to produce an easy counterexample.

I am unable to see where my argument goes wrong. Take the counterexample below and do every step in your proof. What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$? How to write $Aw = \sum_i c_iv_i$ then? What if some $\lambda_i=0$ in $\sum_i \lambda_ic_iv_i = 0$?

Take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\; w=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \cr 1 \cr 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $A^2w=0$, but $Aw=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \cr 0\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $A$ has an eigenvalue $1$, hence is not nilpotent.
